# Авторизация на сайте программно

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser

Почему, когда вбиваю пароль программно, он виден? Т.е. если вводить вручную, то пароль прячется звездочками, а если вставляю строку в графу пароль программно, его видно + если клацну туда мышкой, то все из графы пароль пропадает. С логином проблем нету, вот код    `el[11].SetAttribute("value", "qwerty");`

Comment: вы наверное passwordbox используете? И пароль программно как passwordbox.text присваиваете?

Comment: нет, через сетатрибут, как выше описал